# App <X> isn't working correctly. How can I fix it?

Tags: applications, troubleshooting

I have an application that isn't working correctly. Either it's not launching, or not responding to commands, or some of the functionality isn't doing what I expect.

What are some simple steps I can do to try to fix the issue on my own?

*(This question and answer are intended to be a canonical and generic source for dealing with apps that aren't working quite right.)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The steps to take with an app that just isn't working properly are:

- **Rotate the device**

if that doesn't help

From `Settings | Applications | Manage applications | <application>` or `Settings | Apps | <application>` (depends on your version of Android)

- **Force stop**

if that doesn't help

- **Clear cache**

if that doesn't help

- **Restart the device** (turn off/turn on the device, or use the "restart" option if you have it)

if that doesn't help

- **Clear data**

and if that still doesn't help, try the nuclear option:

- **uninstall and re-install**

Comment: Final step: Report a bug and wait for the next version.

Comment: If you have multiple devices, install the application on other device and verify if same issue exist. Contact the developer instead if the problem persists.

Comment: I would *highly* recommend switching "Clear data" with "Restart the device"! Restarting device helps in many situation and issues an isn't an intrusive way of resolving problems. Clearing app's data certainly **is** an intrusive way, because many applications may not work correctly after that or you may loose a a lot of settings, data etc. (i.e. entire achievements and the whole gameplay usually goes hell, if you try "Clear data" on any kind of game).

Comment: @trejder: That seems reasonable. A restart is certainly not destructive, just time consuming.