# Stock 2.2 Clock app locks phone

Tags: 2.2-froyo, lock-screens, clock

Last week, my LG Optimus V started having a strange problem. Steps:

1. Open Clock
2. Tap "Alarms" icon at the bottom of the screen
3. I must enter my pattern to access alarms
4. Do anything else in Clock
5. … ?
6. Exiting Clock requires entering lock pattern

This happened once before, but I don't remember what I did to fix it, or even if I did anything (it might have just fixed itself).

Had anyone else had this problem? What did you do to fix it?

**Edit:** The screen is locking when the main Clock screen (Activity?) is displayed. Exiting from Alarms (for example) doesn't require unlocking the phone again.

**Edit (2011-12-20):** My solution was to download [Alarm Clock Launcher](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.connor.alarmLauncher) and just bypass opening Clock. My Optimus still has this issue; we'll see if I end up having it on my new Motorola Triumph.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache and/or data for the Clock app? This might help: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it

Comment: All that did was delete my alarms. :-/

Comment: This resolved itself a day or two ago. I have no idea how. Wish I could vote to close.

Comment: The issue has returned. Perhaps I shouldn't have been so hasty in requesting that this question be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured out what the problem was, but I did find a workaround for my particular use case: Install [Alarm Clock Launcher](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.connor.alarmLauncher) ([donate version](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.connor.alarmLauncherDonate)).

That way, I can change the alarm clock settings without having to unlock my device twice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Phone screen used to get locked when i tried to access clock(from widget or from home.) Had to disable the lock pattern.

Anyhow, my solution:

1. goto -> setting -> applications -> Manage Applications -> Running -> Clock
2. Clear data.

activated the lock pattern & clock was working now!!

Cheers!

Comment: Sounded like it was worth a try. Tried: disable screen lock security and clear data for Clock, then 1) set up lock pattern & test Clock **and** (after clearing/disabling again) 2) run Clock *then* reconfigure screen lock. No joy. It sounded so plausible, too. :-/