# gmail app not updating emails

Tags: gmail

My Gmail app that I have installed in my Android 2.3.5 phone has stopped receiving or sending new emails since the last couple of days. What can I do to fix this synchronization issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: did you check in `Settings->Accounts & sync` and make sure that email is still set to sync?

Comment: What changes have you made in the last couple of days? Updated anything on phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had the same problem since upgrading my ROM.
The solution i'm going to present will lead to the loss of unsent emails, so copy them to somewhere.

You have to clear the application data.
To do that you go to:

***Settings > Applications > Manage applications***

look for **Gmail** and **Clear Data**

It will synchronize again with Gmail servers and the problem should be solved.
Send a test e-mail to yourself.

Comment: There are [some other things you can try with a truculent app](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it).