# Default calendar doesn't show any calendar; not able to create a new one

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sync, google-account, google-calendar

My tablet runs Android 4.0.3. The stock calendar app complains that there's no calendar available, however I'm pretty sure that my calendar exists because I can read it online through other devices. I can even sync it with my Windows phone. Moreover, I don't see any button to create a new calendar. In my settings, sync calendar is enabled, and there is no problem with my Google account; I can successfully use Gmail and Play. I must be missing something... without any calendar, the calendar app is useless, uh?

Comment: Have you tried [the usual](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it)?

Comment: The only one thing I didn't try is reinstallation, because I can't find the Calendar app on Play store

Comment: Well, sure. It's a built-in app.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is to remove and re-add that Google account. Either that or a factory reset.