# Unable to dismiss calender alerts on Droid RAZR after 4.0.4 update

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, notifications, calendar

I updated my Droid RAZR to Android 4.0.4 last month. Ever since then I can't dismiss my calendar alerts. No matter what I do they just keep repeating every 5 minutes. I've tried using the dismiss button, the "X" to delete, and tried swiping the notification, but 5 minutes later I get a repeat notification. After about 30 minutes or so, they finally quit, but this is getting extremely annoying since I live by my calendar.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the app data? (I assume you're syncing to Google Calendar.) Have you tried a Force Stop on the calendar app? Have you tried removing the default reminder setting?

Comment: Hey this seemed to have worked.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it