# Google Playstore force-closes

Tags: google-play-store, force-close

I have a Samsung Galaxy 10.1 tablet. I cleaned up some applications, deleting them via settings, and now I receive an error message when I open some applications. The message reads

> The application Google Play Store (`process.com.android.vending`) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

This error keeps appearing, usually three or four times with option of forcing close or reporting error.

Maybe I uninstalled some key file that I needed unknowingly. I cant find anything on updating this application or reinstalling factory setting only for this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried [the usual methods to try fixing a truculent app](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it)?

Comment: Yes, tried the usual methods with no luck.

Comment: You may need to wipe and reload the device?