# Application being closed due to low memory error in Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: internal-storage, force-close

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S device. For the last month my device is continuously showing  "Application being Closed due to Low Memory Error" notifications.

There is no any question about Internal & External Storage memory, both are 16 GB. Also RAM & ROM are almost clear every time.

Please suggest a solution!

Comment: With *continuously* you mean, each time you start an app? Are there apps that do work properly?

Comment: Have you tried the [usual remedies](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it)?

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cache by going to storage-> Internal Storage-> Cached Files