# Can't delete Google Earth cache directory

Tags: force-close, google-earth

I have a Google Nexus with Android 4.1.2 and have just installed Google Earth from Google Play.

Whenever I open it, it shows the loading screen and then:

```
11-18 00:38:34.234: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:34.336: I/ActivityManager(309): Displayed com.google.earth/.EarthActivity: +1s321ms
11-18 00:38:34.336: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:34.367: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:34.383: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:34.398: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:34.414: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:34.437: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:34.453: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
(...)
11-18 00:38:34.976: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:34.992: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:34.992: D/dalvikvm(17379): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
11-18 00:38:35.023: E/chromium(17379): [1118/003835:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(227)] Unable to create cache
11-18 00:38:35.023: W/chromium(17379): [1118/003835:WARNING:chromediskcacheimpl.cc(67)] EARTH: couldn't cleanly open cache backend... retrying.
11-18 00:38:35.031: E/chromium(17379): [1118/003835:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(140)] Unable to move cache folder /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.google.earth/cache/unified_cache_chrome_unified to /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.google.earth/cache/old_unified_cache_chrome_unified_000
11-18 00:38:35.031: E/chromium(17379): [1118/003835:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(227)] Unable to create cache
11-18 00:38:35.031: E/chromium(17379): [1118/003835:ERROR:chromediskcacheimpl.cc(72)] EARTH: Failed back-end creation with result: -2
11-18 00:38:35.031: A/libc(17379): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 17417 (database_login_)
11-18 00:38:35.039: D/dalvikvm(17379): GC_EXPLICIT freed 29K, 10% free 32016K/35527K, paused 4ms+12ms, total 43ms
11-18 00:38:35.039: W/GAV2(17379): Thread[main,5,main]: dispatch call queued.  Need to call GAServiceManager.getInstance().initialize().
11-18 00:38:35.039: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:35.047: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:35.070: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:35.078: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:35.094: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:35.109: W/OpenGLRenderer(17379): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2560x1600, max=2048x2048)
11-18 00:38:35.148: I/DEBUG(126): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-18 00:38:35.148: I/DEBUG(126): Build fingerprint: 'google/yakju/maguro:4.1.2/JZO54K/485486:user/release-keys'
11-18 00:38:35.148: I/DEBUG(126): pid: 17379, tid: 17417, name: database_login_  >>> com.google.earth <<<
11-18 00:38:35.148: I/DEBUG(126): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     r0 5c1bf690  r1 61983c18  r2 61983c1c  r3 61983bc0
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     r4 61983bbc  r5 61983bc0  r6 00000000  r7 61983c18
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     r8 61983c1c  r9 00000001  sl 00000000  fp 5e4e8ab4
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     ip fffffe90  sp 620b3998  lr 5e3b7f3c  pc 5e3b5dc0  cpsr 40000010
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d0  63206f7420656c63  d1  6163206574616568
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d2  322863632e6c7065  d3  616e55205d29370a
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d4  412f306472616364  d5  642f64696f72646e
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d6  2e6d6f632f617461  d7  01a88300676f6f67
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d16 417a883008000000  d17 3fe0000000000000
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d18 3fd5555555555563  d19 3fe279a74590331c
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d20 3fe0c152382d7365  d21 3f1420ec90674fac
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d22 3f133abc50c36001  d23 3f43754291ec7ccf
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d24 3f3083771072f0d7  d25 3f6dcabc44c1354d
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d26 3f582b387a8b46c3  d27 3f96ac9c0e3c8aa0
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d28 3f8261052f31a88b  d29 3fabfa22c97a0286
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0003030000030300
11-18 00:38:35.344: I/DEBUG(126):     scr 80000013
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126): backtrace:
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #00  pc 00d41dc0  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #01  pc 00d43f38  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #02  pc 00d43fa4  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #03  pc 00e71b38  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #04  pc 00e740b8  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #05  pc 00e742b4  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #06  pc 00e74ee0  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #07  pc 00e71188  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #08  pc 00e711c8  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #09  pc 00e764e4  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #10  pc 00e6fd14  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #11  pc 00e8c154  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #12  pc 00e8c2f8  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #13  pc 00e92c3c  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #14  pc 00012bb0  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):     #15  pc 00012308  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126): stack:
11-18 00:38:35.351: I/DEBUG(126):          620b3958  0000fa00  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b395c  00000000  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b3960  620b3990  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b3964  00000000  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b3968  000003e8  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b396c  00000000  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b3970  000003e8  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b3974  dbd64942  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b3978  00000000  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b397c  5e7eac20  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b3980  00000001  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b3984  00000000  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b3988  5e4e8ab4  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b398c  5e54059c  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so (__gnu_ldivmod_helper+24)
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b3990  df0027ad  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b3994  00000000  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):     #00  620b3998  620b3de8  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b399c  620b3b60  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39a0  5e7eac7b  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39a4  5e540398  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39a8  620b39b0  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39ac  61983c1c  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39b0  61983c18  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39b4  620b3b60  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39b8  5e7eac7b  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39bc  5e7eac20  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39c0  00000000  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39c4  5e3b7f3c  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):     #01  620b39c8  61983bbc  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39cc  5c1bf690  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39d0  620b39e0  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39d4  5e3b7fa8  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):     #02  620b39d8  620b39e8  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39dc  620b39ec  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39e0  61983c18  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39e4  61983c1c  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39e8  61983bc0  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39ec  61983bbc  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39f0  5e3b5da0  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39f4  00000000  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39f8  5c63cee0  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b39fc  5e7b9d84  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b3a00  620b3de8  
11-18 00:38:35.359: I/DEBUG(126):          620b3a04  5e4e5b3c  /data/data/com.google.earth/lib/libearthmobile.so
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126): memory near r0:
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126):     5c1bf670 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126):     5c1bf680 00000000 0000002b a6a12a25 5d16f4a0  ....+...%*.....]
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126):     5c1bf690 5e7a3370 5c1bf6b8 00000000 00000000  p3z^...\........
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126):     5c1bf6a0 40000000 00000000 a6a12a03 0000002b  ...@.....*..+...
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126):     5c1bf6b0 a6a12a1d 5d16f4a0 5e7a4950 00010001  .*.....]PIz^....
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126): memory near r1:
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126):     61983bf8 5c1bf690 5df7d0f4 00000000 00000001  ...\...]........
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c08 5e7b9d84 5e3b7170 5c1bf690 5c09ce00  ..{^pq;^...\...\
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c18 5c63ce64 5e3b713c 5c1bf498 5df7d114  d.c\<q;^...\...]
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c28 5da05b98 5dc19658 5c1cf978 5c09cdf0  .[.]X..]x..\...\
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c38 5c7cdfd4 5c277678 5c7cdfd4 5dc78c88  ..|\xv'\..|\...]
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126): memory near r2:
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126):     61983bfc 5df7d0f4 00000000 00000001 5e7b9d84  ...]..........{^
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c0c 5e3b7170 5c1bf690 5c09ce00 5c63ce64  pq;^...\...\d.c\
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c1c 5e3b713c 5c1bf498 5df7d114 5da05b98  <q;^...\...].[.]
11-18 00:38:35.367: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c2c 5dc19658 5c1cf978 5c09cdf0 5c7cdfd4  X..]x..\...\..|\
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c3c 5c277678 5c7cdfd4 5dc78c88 ffffffff  xv'\..|\...]....
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126): memory near r3:
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983ba0 61983bc0 5e3b63ac 61983bc8 61983bcc  .;.a.c;^.;.a.;.a
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983bb0 61983bd0 61983bd4 5e1d65d4 00000049  .;.a.;.a.e.^I...
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983bc0 5c63cec0 5c1bf690 61983c18 61983c1c  ..c\...\.<.a.<.a
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983bd0 61983bc0 61983bbc 5c1cf880 5e3b7f40  .;.a.;.a...\@.;^
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983be0 5e3b5da0 00000000 5e6f9cf4 5e638974  .];^......o^t.c^
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126): memory near r4:
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983b9c 5e7b9d84 61983bc0 5e3b63ac 61983bc8  ..{^.;.a.c;^.;.a
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983bac 61983bcc 61983bd0 61983bd4 5e1d65d4  .;.a.;.a.;.a.e.^
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983bbc 00000049 5c63cec0 5c1bf690 61983c18  I.....c\...\.<.a
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983bcc 61983c1c 61983bc0 61983bbc 5c1cf880  .<.a.;.a.;.a...\
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983bdc 5e3b7f40 5e3b5da0 00000000 5e6f9cf4  @.;^.];^......o^
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126): memory near r5:
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983ba0 61983bc0 5e3b63ac 61983bc8 61983bcc  .;.a.c;^.;.a.;.a
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983bb0 61983bd0 61983bd4 5e1d65d4 00000049  .;.a.;.a.e.^I...
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983bc0 5c63cec0 5c1bf690 61983c18 61983c1c  ..c\...\.<.a.<.a
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983bd0 61983bc0 61983bbc 5c1cf880 5e3b7f40  .;.a.;.a...\@.;^
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983be0 5e3b5da0 00000000 5e6f9cf4 5e638974  .];^......o^t.c^
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126): memory near r7:
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983bf8 5c1bf690 5df7d0f4 00000000 00000001  ...\...]........
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c08 5e7b9d84 5e3b7170 5c1bf690 5c09ce00  ..{^pq;^...\...\
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c18 5c63ce64 5e3b713c 5c1bf498 5df7d114  d.c\<q;^...\...]
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c28 5da05b98 5dc19658 5c1cf978 5c09cdf0  .[.]X..]x..\...\
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c38 5c7cdfd4 5c277678 5c7cdfd4 5dc78c88  ..|\xv'\..|\...]
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126): memory near r8:
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983bfc 5df7d0f4 00000000 00000001 5e7b9d84  ...]..........{^
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c0c 5e3b7170 5c1bf690 5c09ce00 5c63ce64  pq;^...\...\d.c\
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c1c 5e3b713c 5c1bf498 5df7d114 5da05b98  <q;^...\...].[.]
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c2c 5dc19658 5c1cf978 5c09cdf0 5c7cdfd4  X..]x..\...\..|\
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     61983c3c 5c277678 5c7cdfd4 5dc78c88 ffffffff  xv'\..|\...]....
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126): memory near fp:
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     5e4e8a94 002d1384 fffff160 ffffe33c ffffe340  ..-.`...<...@...
11-18 00:38:35.375: I/DEBUG(126):     5e4e8aa4 0016b76f fffec9d8 0016b78e ffffe344  o...........D...
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     5e4e8ab4 e92d4008 e1a00002 e59f3008 e79f3003  .@-......0...0..
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     5e4e8ac4 e12fff33 e8bd8008 002d0b84 e92d45f0  3./.......-..E-.
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     5e4e8ad4 e1a06000 e59f4170 e24ddf69 e59f316c  .`..pA..i.M.l1..
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126): memory near sp:
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     620b3978 00000000 5e7eac20 00000001 00000000  .... .~^........
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     620b3988 5e4e8ab4 5e54059c df0027ad 00000000  ..N^..T^.'......
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     620b3998 620b3de8 620b3b60 5e7eac7b 5e540398  .=.b`;.b{.~^..T^
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     620b39a8 620b39b0 61983c1c 61983c18 620b3b60  .9.b.<.a.<.a`;.b
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     620b39b8 5e7eac7b 5e7eac20 00000000 5e3b7f3c  {.~^ .~^....<.;^
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126): code around pc:
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     5e3b5da0 e92d45f0 e24dd014 e5906008 e1a05003  .E-...M..`...P..
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     5e3b5db0 e59d4030 e1a07001 e59fc078 e1a08002  0@...p..x.......
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     5e3b5dc0 e5963000 e28d0008 e59f106c e08fc00c  .0......l.......
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     5e3b5dd0 e1a0200d e58d5000 e593a00c e08f1001  . ...P..........
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     5e3b5de0 e28d3004 e58d4004 e12fff3c e1a01007  .0...@..<./.....
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126): code around lr:
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     5e3b7f1c e5900000 e58d0000 e08100ce e5921000  ................
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     5e3b7f2c e5932000 e59d3010 e5933000 e12fff3c  . ...0...0..<./.
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     5e3b7f3c e8bd800e e92d4030 e24dd024 e5902010  ....0@-.$.M.. ..
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     5e3b7f4c e28d3018 e5905014 e5904018 e590e01c  .0...P...@......
11-18 00:38:35.383: I/DEBUG(126):     5e3b7f5c e590c020 e2800008 e58d5008 e8900003   ........P......
11-18 00:38:35.898: I/BootReceiver(309): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_00 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
11-18 00:38:35.969: D/Zygote(129): Process 17379 terminated by signal (11)
11-18 00:38:36.023: D/dalvikvm(309): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3077K, 20% free 26285K/32519K, paused 116ms, total 117ms
11-18 00:38:36.039: W/InputDispatcher(309): channel '42b9fe38 com.google.earth/com.google.earth.EarthActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
11-18 00:38:36.039: E/InputDispatcher(309): channel '42b9fe38 com.google.earth/com.google.earth.EarthActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-18 00:38:36.047: I/WindowState(309): WIN DEATH: Window{42b9fe38 com.google.earth/com.google.earth.EarthActivity paused=false}
11-18 00:38:36.047: I/ActivityManager(309): Process com.google.earth (pid 17379) has died.
11-18 00:38:36.047: W/InputDispatcher(309): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '42b9fe38 com.google.earth/com.google.earth.EarthActivity (server)'
11-18 00:38:36.047: W/ActivityManager(309): Force removing ActivityRecord{421393e0 com.google.earth/.EarthActivity}: app died, no saved state
11-18 00:38:36.047: W/WindowManager(309): Force-removing child win Window{42d0cf68 SurfaceView paused=false} from container Window{42b9fe38 com.google.earth/com.google.earth.EarthActivity paused=false}
11-18 00:38:36.055: W/WindowManager(309): Failed looking up window
11-18 00:38:36.055: W/WindowManager(309): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@426b1220 does not exist
11-18 00:38:36.055: W/WindowManager(309):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7640)
11-18 00:38:36.055: W/WindowManager(309):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7631)
11-18 00:38:36.055: W/WindowManager(309):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:854)
11-18 00:38:36.055: W/WindowManager(309):   at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:449)
11-18 00:38:36.055: W/WindowManager(309):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-18 00:38:36.055: I/WindowState(309): WIN DEATH: null
11-18 00:38:36.055: I/WindowManager(309): WINDOW DIED Window{42b9fe38 com.google.earth/com.google.earth.EarthActivity paused=false}
```

**What is really happening? And how can I fix it?**

Comment: Have you tried the [usual remedies](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it) to use with a truculent app?

Comment: Yes, but i cant seem to clear the cache when the app is installed. The button doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I did it.

I tried to delete the folder /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.google.earth but even with root/su I was unable to.

So I renamed it and it was renammed successfully.

Next time I opened the app it worked. But I still have a folder of 13MB that I can't delete.

Suggestions?

UPDATE:

I found [this](http://www.galaxynexusforum.com/forum/rescue-squad/5868-cannot-delete-two-folders-sdcard.html) that suggests:

> I see in mount points something that gets my attention
>
> ```
> /dev/fuse on /storage/sdcard0 type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other)
> ```
>
> Here you can see that /data/media is mounted with specific user and
>   group ID. I discover by executing `ps` and `id` commands that 1023 ID
>   belongs to media_rw user with wich the /data/media folder is mounted.
>   I think login as media_rw user should do the trick but what I did in
>   order to delete the folders was:
>
> 1. Login as root (unnecesary if connected via SSH with SSHDroid)
>
>    `su`
> 2. Mount /system with write permissions
>
>    `mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk0p9 /system`
> 3. Run sdcard command again (as root)
>
>    `/system/bin/sdcard /data/media 1023 1023`
> 4. Go to /data/media and delete the unwanted folders (let's say they are called .trash y .garbage)
>
>    `rm -rf .trash .garbage`
> 5. Mount /system with read only permissions again (for security reasons)
>
>    `mount -o ro,remount -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk0p9 /system`
> 6. Check that the folders doesn't exists
>
>    `ls -lsa /data/media/`
>
> the output must be something like this (no .trash or .garbage folders
>   in here )
>
> ```
> # ls -lsa /data/media/
> total 443361
>    4 drwxrwxr-x   14 media_rw media_rw      4096 Oct 12 10:25 .
>    4 drwxrwx--x   23 system   system        4096 Oct 12 06:01 ..
>    4 drwxrwxr-x    2 media_rw media_rw      4096 Oct 12 06:06 .mmsyscache
>    4 drwxrwxr-x    2 media_rw media_rw      4096 Oct 12 06:01 Alarms
>    4 drwxrwxr-x    3 media_rw media_rw      4096 Oct 12 06:03 Android
>    4 drwxrwxr-x    2 media_rw media_rw      4096 Oct 12 06:01 DCIM
>    4 drwxrwxr-x    2 media_rw media_rw      4096 Oct 12 06:01 Download
>    4 drwxrwxr-x    5 media_rw media_rw      4096 Oct 12 06:09 GOLauncherEX
>    4 drwxrwxr-x    2 media_rw media_rw      4096 Oct 12 06:01 Movies
>    4 drwxrwxr-x    2 media_rw media_rw      4096 Oct 12 06:01 Music
>    4 drwxrwxr-x    2 media_rw media_rw      4096 Oct 12 06:01 Notifications
>    4 drwxrwxr-x    3 media_rw media_rw      4096 Oct 12 08:55 Pictures
>    4 drwxrwxr-x    2 media_rw media_rw      4096 Oct 12 06:01 Ringtones
> 136520 -rw-rw-r--    1 media_rw media_rw 139791302 Oct 11 23:06 cm-10-20121011.zip
> 85104 -rw-rw-r--    1 media_rw media_rw  87138923 Oct 11 23:02 gapps-jb.zip
>    4 drwxrwxr-x    3 media_rw media_rw      4096 Oct 12 06:06 xiialive
> ```

This may solve other problems like this.