# E-mail (imap client) sync stopped because of low memory, and will not start again, even after freeing 60Mb

Tags: email, imap, insufficient-memory

I have a Motorola XT303 running Android 2.3.6, and I use the email client (with an IMAP server). The email worked fine until two days ago: I tried to download an application that was too large for the internal memory, and the installation failed. Right after that email syncing stopped -- whenever I asked it to sync, a message popped up telling me that email syncing wouldn't be done because the phone was low on memory. However, even after freeing 60Mb of internal memory, the email client still refuses to sync.

I have tried stopping the email app from the task manager and restarting the phone, but that didn't help.

I also thought I'd just download another email client, but since this is software that will have access to my email server passwords, I'd rather use the client I'm already using.

*edit*: but if there is an email client that is open source and well-known, then I could just as well switch...

So... How can I get the email app to start syncing again?

Comment: Have you tried all of [these steps](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/13348/267)?

Comment: Yes, I did -- ecxept for uninstalling and reinstalling (how do I do that?)

Comment: That step won't work for pre-installed apps (you cannot uninstall them). How much free storage do you have? Maybe you have to free a little more (clear some more app caches, that doesn't hurt and nothing gets lost that way), also your download might still stick around somewhere in temp (or rather `/data/local`).

Comment: I have 60 Mb. But after user1 mentioned uninstalling, I thought that maybe just cleaning all app data (not just cache) would work. But then I realized that there is an open source version of the email app -- k9-- and I tend to trust these, since the probability of someone including malicious code is very low (after all, the source is open). I didn't know that there was an open source email client for Android. I switched to k9 and I'm now happy with it.