# Contact list crashing

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-nexus

Every other day, my Contacts List will crash, and the only way for me to access it is to power off the phone.

What is happening for this to happen, and what can I do to prevent it in future?

Comment: This is the People app, right? Have you tried the [usual things to do with a truculent app](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it)?

Answer (score -1):

You might have an app that's adding spurious records to your calling list. Do you have any "alternative phone" application (I had problems with an app called Amivox). I created a small app to fix the problem for me, the code is linked below.

**EDIT**:
The app source code: https://github.com/gardarh/android-callogfixer (removed link to binary)

Comment: Please note that the APK has no documentation or source code available, therefore the behaviour is unknown. One should always be careful when installing third-party APKs from untrusted or unknown sources.

Comment: There, added a link to the source code.