# The application Market Feedback Agent has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: google-play-store, crashes, youtube

> The application Market Feedback Agent (process com.google.android.feedback) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

I keep getting this error message when YouTube crashes. I click to report the problem, then this error occurs. I tried to manually visit https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.feedback to check for an update but nothing was found. Android version 2.3.4. Neither Verizon, Motorola, nor Google will update it.

How can I fix this problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you restarted the phone? Have you tried clearing the data/cache for the Play Store and/or YouTube?

Comment: @AlEverett It's been doing this for several months. The phone reboots itself nearly every day. Will try clearing cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step for any of these force close issues is to clear the cache and/or data from the problem app. Whether it's the Play Store or YouTube that is the problem is unclear; you may end up doing both.

1. Open `Settings`
2. `Apps`
3. Scroll down to the app you want and tap to open App Info. (If it's a system app (without updates) you may need to swipe left to "All" in order to find it.)
4. Tap the <kbd>Clear cache</kbd> button. If that doesn't work, return and tap <kbd>Clear data</kbd>

See also: [App <X> isn't working correctly. How can I fix it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: Even after doing this, the problem quickly reoccurs later. I've since given up on Android and bought an iPhone.