# Google Play Store force closing

Tags: google-play-store, force-close

I have a Karbonn S5 Titanium. Whenever I try to open the Google Play Store, it gets closed within a second. A notification saying 'your google store has stopped unfortunately' keeps coming every 2 minutes. I can't download any apps or access a few of them. What can be done to set it right ?

Comment: Have you tried to clear cache (and, if that did not help, data) from the playstore app?

Comment: [App X isn't working correctly. How can I fix it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13347)

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall any Play Store updates, and then rerun the app; if all goes well, it will re-update the app, and the force closing should stop. If it still force closes, and you don't have much data on your device, you can try to factory reset the phone. That usually makes my Play Store work fine (although I don't have S5).

Answer (score 0):

You could try updating to the latest play store. See [AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/25/download-latest-google-play-store-4-2-9/). Doing this fixed the same issue for me when I updated my Nexus 7 to android 4.3. It was crashing like yours, I updated (and cleared the cache and data) and the Play Store started working again. You don't need to be rooted, you can simply install it. It's perfectly safe as it is signed by Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rooted and have ClockworkMod recovery, you can try these steps:

1. Uninstall Google play services.
2. Boot into recovery and select "wipe data".
3. Then select "clear cache".
4. Then select "advanced" and in the sub-menu select "wipe dalivk cache".
5. Then go back and select reboot.

Now the Play Store will start working.

Comment: And all your apps and data are gone. What you describe here is a manual factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

In Settings -> Apps -> All, Try clearing cache for Google Play Services, Google Play Store, and Google Services Framework, and restart.

If that doesn't do the trick, try clearing cache and data for all three services. Restart, and start google play. It should ask you to accept the terms and conditions and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue follow this solutions.

Solution 1. Clear Cache from Google Play Store

Solution 2. Uninstall Updates of Google Play store and then try restarting your android device

Solution 3. Install Latest Google Play Store.

Solution 4. Still if you are unable to solve try doing factory reset.

In my article, I have listed all these solutions in a step by step process with screenshots so if you are unable to understand check out my article on [How to Solve Google Play Store Keeps Crashing Issue on Android](http://www.indabaa.com/google-play-store-keeps-force-closing/)

Disclosure: I'm the author of the linked article.