# New emails not showing up in Gmail app

Tags: gmail

I have 2 different Android devices: a Samsung Galaxy Reverb phone and a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 tablet.

On both devices, I have just recently noticed that the official Gmail app is no longer showing new email messages in the list.  When new emails come in, I get Android notifications. If I select the email in the notification bar, then it brings up the new email.

But if I just go to the Gmail app, then I don't see new emails in the list. I have to manually change from Priority Inbox to Normal Inbox (or vice versa) in order for the new emails to show up in my list.

Is this happening for anyone else? Is there a fix for it?

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. I have all my inboxes set to Default but I can't seem to get my new messages to show consistently. I end up having to go in and tell it to show Priority box and then they'll show up. So annoying.

Comment: Have you tried the steps listed in [App X isn't working correctly. How can I fix it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13347)

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the Gmail app, go to settings (click the three vertical dots in the top right), click on your email account and select "Default Inbox" as your Inbox type.

I expect this is happening because you've got "Priority Inbox" set as your default and this doesn't show all your messages.

Comment: I have tried both Inbox types and the problem exists on both.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I needed to clear all the data from the app so it would need to re-sync everything again.
Seemed to fix the problem for me after that.