# contacts crashes sporadically

Tags: contacts, force-close

Sometimes, when I click on the phone icon on my Galaxy S3, it freezes for a second and then says that the app Contacts has crashed. Afterwards I can reopen contacts with no problem.

This happens sporadically; sometimes it crashes multiple times in a day, sometimes it lasts a week without problems.

Comment: Could you let us know how often this happens (Every day? Every hour?), and perhaps which version of Android you're running? Did this start happening after you installed another app or some other event?

Comment: I'm not sure what started this or I would of uninstalled it. 4.1.3 and it varies when it happened some times it will be multiple times in a day then not for a week or so.

Comment: Have you tried [the usual](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13347/267)?

Comment: I have, I'm probably just gonna end up reformating