# I uninstalled updates for Google play services

Tags: google-play-services

I uninstalled updates for Google play service and now I can't even use my Google play store, help me please

I'm using a Samsung galaxy grand quattro

Comment: Have you tried the [usual remedies for an app that is misbehaving](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this link - [Google Play Apk](https://mega.co.nz/#!Z9IWmRaR!HQ-5istE6Vsw5-pWMg8rPE6iOONfYirxaMgfxfMqxhQ). Try upgrading it later if an update is available.
**Edit:**
Open any browser and go to [PlayStore](http://play.google.com) and try to install any application so that website may prompt to install Play Store before continuing.
(or)
[1](https://mega.co.nz/#!Z9IWmRaR!HQ-5istE6Vsw5-pWMg8rPE6iOONfYirxaMgfxfMqxhQ) - There is a chance that you've unknowingly disabled Play Store permanently in App Manager. To re-enable it again just follow Menu>Settings>Apps/App Manager>Disabled apps and enable it.
[2](http://play.google.com) - You can also use apps like [CleanMaster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=en) to perform above job.

Comment: https://mega.co.nz/#!Z9IWmRaR!HQ-5istE6Vsw5-pWMg8rPE6iOONfYirxaMgfxfMqxhQ  *_isn't a link to the playstore*

Comment: @HasH_BrowN - Oh I know it man! You don't find Google Play app in Google Play so I gave that link to give it a try. You've downvoted my answer and discovered a great truth that it's not a link to Play Store.

Comment: Then you need to include details that are relevant to the question. Anybody reading that unedited answer you had originally wrote would think that was a link to an actual apk. Now the updated answer addresses the question,  thank you for clarifying. Down vote removed!!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on my LG G2(purchased a few months ago) with the google play store. Earlier I used Playstore to download as many free apps as needed. But then to save the battery backup time, I disabled all the apps that used to restart automatically, each time I closed them. But after disabling them from task manager, play store stopped working and even after re-enabling it, it did not start. Even the apps downloaded through play store did not function and used to give info that for running this app I need to update play store and after opening play store to update, it used to straightway say no connection. I called google support, and did a bit of troubleshooting on it remotely, but it did not help, they asked me to take the device to the service centre. But as I barely find any time in any week, I decided to do it myself and used the factory mode reset option and now it is functioning again wonderfully.