# Google Maps won't work

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps app takes like half a minute to update my location every time, navigation instructions don't update when I move, and it doesn't automatically reroute, I have to restart navigation.

I can't use it, it doesn't work at all! How can I fix this?

- Motorola Moto G4 Play
- Android 6.0.1

Comment: Some more information might be nice, like what device you are using, what your Android version is, etc.  With the limited information you have provided one can only offer sympathy instead of help.

Comment: @OrganicMarble lol sorry, done

Comment: Have you tried the [usual troubleshooting steps](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13347/267)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now it worked. After trying lots of things, the way I made it work was just reinstalling the app.